# Find number based on text right before Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, string, python-2.7

How can I extract 34980, and 100329 from the following snippet using python:

```
<tr id="product_34980" class="even">
<tr id="variant_100329" class="variantRow">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most general solution, but it works for the snippet above:

```
import re

html = """
    <tr id="product_34980" class="even">
    <tr id="variant_100329" class="variantRow">
"""

ids = re.findall(r'id="\w+_(\d+)"', html)
```

Comment: Escape backslashes or use raw string. `re.findall` require at least two arguments.

Comment: Can you modify this to return the full strings: 'product_34980' and 'variant_100329'?

Comment: @ChuckDickens: Of course. Use this code instead: `re.findall(r'id="(\w+_\d+)"', html)`

Comment: @falsetru. Right! I was in a hurry. Tks! :)

Comment: duh, I should have thought of that@!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Using [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.isdigit), following code extract digits from each line.

```
>>> lines = '''<tr id="product_34980" class="even">
... <tr id="variant_100329" class="variantRow">
... '''
>>> [filter(str.isdigit, line) for line in lines.splitlines()]
['34980', '100329']
```

---

**UPDATE** Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de):

```
import lxml.html

html_string = '''
<tr id="product_34980" class="even">
<tr id="variant_100329" class="variantRow">
'''

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html_string)
for tr in root.cssselect('tr.even, tr.variantRow'):
    print(tr.get('id')) # => product_34980
    print(tr.get('id').rsplit('_', 1)[-1]) # => 34980
```

Comment: The snippet is a small extract of a full html page.  These numbers are not the only numbers on the page.  I need to figure out how to extract the 'product_34980' and 'variant_100329' from the text so I can use that in an Xpath query.

Comment: @ChuckDickens, I updated the answer with another solution that use `lxml`.